# React based Web Form builder UI that provides workflow (mulit-page forms)

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui, formbuilder, react-jsonschema-forms

I am familiar with `react-jsonschema-form`, but what I am looking for goes beyond that.

What I need is the ability, perhaps in JSON, to specify multi-page forms and a workflow between those forms (i.e. conditional logic, sub flows, forward and back progression).

There are definitely a lot of Form builders out there, both free and commercial, but so far, I have not found what I am looking for.

Any ideas or do you know of a library or a product that would fit my needs?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `react-jsonschema-form` but it may be worth looking at integrating django with your frontend and using viewflow as a workflow library. Viewflow will bring some structure to your form process. I am yet to use viewflow in my project so cannot offer any more advice on its use.

References:

https://www.djangoproject.com/
http://viewflow.io/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31443216)